# Mac OS - add app to autostart with launchctl

Tags: macos, autostart

I can start application with launchctl like this: launchctl submit -l ProgramName -- open -g -b com.company.ProgramName and it works great! I can kill app, and it'll re-run again even if it crashes.

But when i logout or reboot Mac, my process is no longer run. Or, in some cases, it runs not with ProgramName (whitch is my application name), but with name of executable file in ProgramName.app/Contents/MacOS/program_name

Such situation with plist files. I run command launchctl -w /Users/my_username/Library/LaunchAgents and process works fine! But after restart i can't see it.

I prefer first method to load processes, any suggestions why process doesn't autoload after reboot?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set "RunAtLoad" to "true" for it to start your application when user logs in.

But there is no way to set RunAtLoad from command-line when using "submit". At least not in the version of launchctl.c that I checked online.

It looks like you have to create a .plist file with "load", instead of using "submit".

What is more annoying is that launchctl's "load", can not take stdin as input to .plist filename, either with no-argument, or name "-". Shame, perhaps the developers of launchctl are not from Unix background. This means you are forced to litter your short-lived file somewhere on the file-system, at least until you have it loaded.

Comment: Hmm it seems from 10.5 "OnDemand" and "RunAtLoad" where both replaced with "KeepAlive". I was reading older documentation it would seem.